# Can I list a repository content before adding it to search for a package?

Tags: package-management, repository

I want to keep my /etc/apt/sources.list clean and I'm looking for a way to look for a package in a repository **before** adding it to my system.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can browse the link to the repository in your browser. if you look there for the Packages files (usually Packages.gz and Packages.bz2) in the correct folder under `dists`, you can download that file and uncompress it. It contains a list of all the packages of the archive.

Answer (score 0):

For example; if the repository is: http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/; you could simple enter the site with web browser and look for the package you want. The packages are in "pool" directory.

Example: http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alien/